# python program which return max count of chacharter like input=aabbbcczaaaabbbccc ouput=a3b3c3z1

Tags: python-3.x

python program which return max count of chacharter like input=aabbbcczaaaabbbccc ouput=a3b3c3z1
st=aabbbcczaaaabbbccc
ouput=a3b3c3z1
def maxCount(st):
return
maxCount(st)

Comment: Do you mean max *consecutive* time?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant max **consecutive** times, then this code will work (it returns a dictionary):

```py
def maxCount(st):
    counts = dict()
    last = ''
    tmp = 0
    for c in st:
        if last == c:
            tmp += 1
        elif last != '':
            if last in list(counts.keys()):
                counts[last] = max(counts[last], tmp)
                tmp = 1
            else:
                counts[last] = tmp
                tmp = 1
        last = c
    return counts
    
print(maxCount('aabbbcczaaaabbbccc'))
```